# d3.js как написать функцию приближения к точке на карте

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Есть карта отрисованная при помощи D3.js
На карте есть точки отрисованные таким образом:

```js
const point = g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(places).enter()
      .append("circle")
      .on("click", clicked)
      .attr("cx", function (d) { console.log(projection(d)); return projection(d)[0]; })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
      .attr("r", "5px")
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      .attr("fill", "red")
```

Вопрос в том как написать функцию для зума к этой точке по клику, если сможете написать объяснение как это сделать будет круто.
https://bl.ocks.org/fdlk/076469462d00ba39960f854df9acda56 - я не смог разобраться с этим кодом.